# How to call a HTTPS function that has timeout of 1hour from a function triggered by cloud storage which has a timeout of 9min

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a 1st gen function that runs whenever a file is created in the cloud storage. Currently I've set the timeoutSeconds to the max allowed which is 540s. But the function sometimes times out when there are a lot of data to process and the runtime exceeds 540s.

I tried to convert the whole function to a 2nd gen function so that i can access the 60min timeout allowed in 2nd gen but in the documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/manage-functions it is mentioned.

> The maximum value for timeoutSeconds is 540, or 9 minutes.

But in the page https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta its written

> HTTP functions can now have a 1 hour timeout (up from 9 minutes previously) if needed for long-running workloads.

This is confusing to me as my function needs to be triggered whenever a file is uploaded to the cloud storage, but the cloud storage trigger doesnt allow more than 540s timeout. So can i call a 2nd gen https function, which allows 1hour timeout from either a 2nd gen or 1st gen cloud storage triggered function? and can i send data back in the response of the https function even though the https function runs for longer than the storage triggered function?

Any other suggestions as to how to deal with the timeoutSeconds is greatly appreciated as im new to cloud functions and backend in general.

EDIT:
Ive tried to create a 2nd gen function like this, this function is being invoked by the one below (executeAllTask) which is a 1st gen function.

```
exports.executetask = onRequest(
{ timeoutSeconds: 3600, memory: "1GiB", cors: true },
(req, res) => {
    if (res.method === "POST") {
        const fileBucket = req.body.fileBucket
        const taskId = req.body.taskId
        const filePath = req.body.filePath
        const contentType = req.body.contentType
        const fileName = req.body.fileName
        processTask(fileBucket, taskId, filePath, contentType, fileName)
            .then(res.status(200).end())
            .catch((err) => {
                logger.log(err);
                res.status(405).end();
            })
    }
    else {
        res.status(405);
        res.end();
    }
});

exports.executeAllTask = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540,memory:"1GB" }).storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
try {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
  const filePath = object.name; 
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  const pathParts = path.dirname(filePath).split('/')
  const taskId = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];
  const contentType = object.contentType; 


  if (fileName == 'response') {
    return admin.firestore().collection("tasks").doc(taskId).set(
      {
        taskRunning: false,
        dateCompleted: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
      },
      { merge: true }
    )
  }


  if (!contentType.startsWith('application/')) {
    return functions.logger.log('This is not an blob.');
  }
  const body = {
    fileBucket, filePath, fileName, taskId, contentType
  }
  await fetch('https://executetask-<random-hash>-<region>.a.run.app', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });


} catch (error) {
  functions.logger.log(error);
}})
```

But whenever i try to deploy the executetask function i get the error

> HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service
> executetask. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale
> may not exceed 10.
> Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity,
> decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.

Comment: Have you deployed a version 2 function? If, yes did you try to set the timeout to be longer than 540 seconds? You can change the timeout via command line or the Google Cloud web GUI. In the consol go to the runtime tab and enter a larger number in the Timeout field. Does the Google Cloud web GUI let you? Edit your question with more details on how you deployed a version 2 function. Note: Your first link is for version 1 functions. Your second link is for version 2.

Comment: Include the deployment command. Notice the error `maxScale may not exceed 10`. Do you have a quota problem (meaning you do not have enough quota to create an instance)?

Comment: I've edited the question, I'm confused, is version 2 function the same as 2nd gen? because the first link is under Cloud functions 2nd Gen Public Preview>Write Functions>Manage and Deploy functions. Also, I'm using the firebase CLI to deploy the functions.

Comment: @JohnHanley I deploy the function using firebase deploy, and as to my knowledge i dont have a quota problem as in the quotas under IAM and admin it shows 0% Current Usage Percentage for all quotas.

Comment: Can you share the steps to recreate the issue

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the term "generation 2" instead of "version 2". They are the same service.